# The edit/delete dropdown on the developer story items feels weird

Tags: feature-request, developer-story

When currently editing your position in the developer story, one moves their cursor to the small edit icon in the top right of the box. However, I tried scrolling to the center of the 'edit' button (as per the image provided) and the box immediately disappears.

[image]

Normal people moving their mouse

[image]

My trajectory, being obviously annoying.

[image: gif]

A gif demonstrating the behavior.

Now I know moving my cursor down immediately will solve this terrible issue I'm having- but wouldn't a small- say 100ms delay improve my user experience of this functionality?

(including a mandatory hand drawn red circle for this question to be taken seriously).

[image]

Comment: Your hand-drawn circle is too perfect for this question to be taken seriously.

Comment: Might help having a gif in the question.

Comment: IMO, dropdows that have to clicked (not hovered) should stay open until you click somewhere else. Also, the behavior I described is actually used on SO and SE sites, e.g. the reputation box, notification box, the review and help menu in the top bar

Comment: @chade_ that's the point, this popup activates on mouseover and disappears if you move the slightest bit away from it.

Comment: @CodeCaster thanks for the gif! I can't make one here, but this quite describes my issue :).